# Filter not applied to all image sizes

Tags: attachments, images

I have a callback applied to `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes` to add attributes to the generated image html.

```
function add_lazyload_to_attachment_image($attr, $attachment)
{
    if (strpos($attr['class'], 'lazyload') !== false) {
        $attr['data-src'] = $attr['src'];

        if (isset($attr['srcset'])) {
            $attr['data-srcset'] = $attr['srcset'];
            $attr['data-sizes'] = "auto";
            $attr['srcset'] = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==";
        }
    }

    return $attr;
}
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'add_lazyload_to_attachment_image', 30, 2);
```

But the function does not get applied some custom image sizes. This filter works for the default image sizes present in Wordpress.

I want this filter to work for all custom image sizes. Please help.

Comment: All your image sizes have the `lazyload` class?

Comment: Yes. @MikeNGarrett

Comment: The code above works for me. Can you show how you're calling the image? For example, I'm using `echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full', false, array( 'class' => 'lazyload' ) );`

Comment: `wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'property-thumb', false, array( 'class' => 'lazyload' ) );` where `property-thumb` is a custom image size of  `540 x 380` I have added.

Comment: Wow almost exactly the same. I would look into other plugins or functionality that's hooking in to the image output. This works as you intended with WordPress core.

Comment: Yes.. as I have mentioned. This works with WP predefined image sizes. Although this has worked for me before on other projects.